# Modify AndroidManifest.xml through Shoutem platform

Tags: android, react-native, shoutem

I would like to add/modify AndroidManifest.xml, for permissions (FINE_LOCATION) in this case, so I looked how it's done in the Shoutem firebase extension (https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/tree/master/shoutem-firebase).

In the preview app this is not needed, that app already got permissions for location (and more), but I assumed that this should be added to my custom extension if I would like to submit it to the Play Store / manually install it on my Android device (please correct me if I assumed wrong).

## Problem

Did I go through the correct steps for modifying AndroidManifest.xml using the Shoutem platform?

## Outcome

Build succeeds using Shoutem CLI, but CLI hangs on copying to builds folder, installation on Android device fails

I did the following things:
- Created a AndroidManifest.xml in /app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.shoutemapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Updated app/package.json, added:

```
,
"rnpm": {
    "commands": {
        "postlink": "node node_modules/[myusername].[extensionname]/scripts/run.js"
    }
}
```

Content of /scripts/run.js:

```
require('./android/copy_custom_manifest');
```

Content of /android/copy_custom_manifest:

Same as firebase extension, with my username.extensionname in extensionPath:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len*/
 'use_strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const MANIFEST_FILE = 'AndroidManifest.xml';

const extensionPath = './node_modules/[myusername].[extensionname]';
const manifestFilePath = `${extensionPath}/${MANIFEST_FILE}`;
const customManifestFileDestination = `android/app/src/customized/${MANIFEST_FILE}`;

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(manifestFilePath);
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(customManifestFileDestination, { flags: 'a' });
readStream.on('error', console.log.bind(null, `Unable to read from ${manifestFilePath}`));
writeStream.on('error', console.log.bind(null, `Unable to write to ${customManifestFileDestination}`));
writeStream.on('finish', console.log.bind(null, `copied ${manifestFilePath} to ${customManifestFileDestination}`));

fs.truncate(customManifestFileDestination, 0, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    process.exitCode = 1;
    throw new Error(`Unable to overwrite, ${manifestFilePath} does not exist`);
  }

  console.log(`Overwrite ${customManifestFileDestination} with ${manifestFilePath}`);
  readStream.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

I'm not getting errors in the build process, but the app won't install on a physical device, using:

`shoutem build-android`

Console output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 mins 43.478 secs
This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Copying .apk to /Users/matthijs/Documents/shoutem/builds
--> It stops on this last line (copying .apk), no error.
There was one error however:
[5/3/2017, 12:06:07 PM] <START> Initializing Packager
[5/3/2017, 12:06:07 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[5/3/2017, 12:06:07 PM] <END> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (108ms)
[5/3/2017, 12:06:07 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[5/3/2017, 12:06:07 PM] <END> Building Haste Map (304ms)
[5/3/2017, 12:06:07 PM] <END> Initializing Packager (473ms)
platform.buildPlatform(...).finally is not a function
If you think this error is caused by bug in the shoutem command, you can report the issue here: https://github.com/shoutem/cli/issues
Make sure to include the information printed using the `shoutem last-error` command
> @shoutem/mobile-app@0.56.0 build /private/var/folders/xp/strzbzt15zz4k1pvmgc99rj40000gn/T/tmp-8209NeOBTGdT1e1B
> node scripts/build "--platform" "android" "--outputDirectory" "/Users/matthijs/Documents/shoutem/builds"
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preCustomizedReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the @shoutem/cli. A newer version has now been published (v0.8.143), which resolves that issue. Update your @shoutem/cli and your build should be error free.

The CLI should prompt you to update it the next time you use it, so just using

```
$ shoutem -v
```

Will prompt you with a Yes/No update option.

If you decline the update, you won't be prompted again, but you will be warned:

"Warning: This is an outdated version of shoutem CLI"

And you can install the newest version with:

```
$ npm install -g @shoutem/cli
```